# How do I close a thread safely?

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
     pthread_create(&thread, NULL, AcceptLoop, (void *)this);
```

I have declared like this and inside of the AcceptLoop function I have infinity while loop. I'd like to close this thread when the server is closed. I have read pthread_cancel and pthread_join but I am not sure which one is better and safer. I would like to hear some detailed instructions or tutorials. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would like to exit the worker thread by signalling from the main thread.

Inside `AcceptLoop` instead of looping infinitiely you loop on a condition, you can set the condition through your main thread, You will have to use some synchronization for this variable. Once the variable is set from main thread the worker thread `AcceptLoop` would break out and you can then call `pthread_exit`.

if you would like your main thread to wait for child thread to exit you can use `pthread_join` to do so.

In general, A child thread can exit in three conditions:

1. calling `pthread_exit`.
2. calling `pthread_cancel`.
3. The thread function returns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything, just returning from the thread function will end the thread cleanly.  You can alternatively call `pthread_exit()` but I'd rather return.
`pthread_cancel()` is scary and complicated/hard to get right.  Stay clear if possible.
`pthread_join()` is mostly needed if you want to know when thread finishes and are interested in the `return` value.

Ooops, I'm wrong.  It's been some time.  In order for what I said to be true, you must detach from your thread.  Otherwise you'll need to call pthread_join:

> Either pthread_join(3) or
>   pthread_detach() should be called for
>   each thread
>          that an application creates, so that system resources for the thread
>   can be
>          released.  (But note that the resources of all threads are freed
>   when the
>          process terminates.)

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html

Comment: This all depends on if the thread has been detached.  If it has not, then you will need to pthread_join the thread in order to clean up the threads memory.  If you have detached then yes returning from the main function or pthread_exit().